# jQuery validation not work in select2 tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I add jQuery validation plugin for my form and I work with select2 plugin. for check select2 validation I add `ignore: "",` for validatioin plugin like this :

```
$("#form").validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        tags: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        tags: {
            required: "error ! required field",
        },
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-control').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'div',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

This worked and show required message But when i choose tags, form validation not work and not remove required message. How do fix this ?!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X6V2s/193/)

Comment: This is a super common request for 3.5.x ([related GitHub ticket](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/215)) and it was fixed for 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Validation plugin is automatically triggered by certain user events.  However, since Select2 is dynamically changing a hidden `input` value in the background, no validation is automatically triggered.

You simply need a `change` handler that programmatically triggers a validation test whenever the value of the hidden element is changed.

```
$('input[name="tags"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();    
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/X6V2s/194/**